# mod_rewrite wont take third rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I've got a problem with my mod_rewrite code. I want the rewrite to happen based on 3 rules:

1. If it is not a known file (images, xml), reroute to index.php (For Zend MVC)
2. If there is no www before the domain name, add it
3. If the requested url is www.domain.com/page/pagename, rewrite to www.domain.com/page/show/id/pagename

So far I've got the first two working, but I can't seem to get the third one working. This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fietsnl.nl
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.fietsnl.nl [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^page/([a-zA-Z_]+)$
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ /page/show/id/$1 [L]
```

If I request http://www.domain.com/page/pagename, it still rederects to the first rule
Can you put me in the right direction on what to change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L in

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```

Tells mod_rewrite to stop processing rules so the two below that will never get processed in the case that the file doesn't exist on the server.

I'm not a master at mod_rewrite, but by moving the last rule before the first rule it should fix you're problem.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^page/([a-zA-Z_]+)$
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ /page/show/id/$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fietsnl.nl
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.fietsnl.nl [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for explaining. I still don't get the result of having http://www.domain.com/page/pagename to go to http://www.domain.com/page/show/id/pagename though. Is there something else I messed up?

Comment: I'm not quite 100% sure why (like I said I'm not expert) but it seems something is wrong with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^page/([a-zA-Z_]+)$`. If I get rid of that, it works as expected on my server.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `{REQUEST_URI}` starts with a /. So `%{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/([a-zA-Z_]+)$` should work.

Comment: Ah, it seems to route correctly, only the Zend MVC seems to take the original value. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Rules are matched in the order that they appear.

I assume that `page/pagename` is not an existing file or directory, so it will match the first rule and no other rules will me processed.

In general, you want to have rules arranged from most specific to least specific, and have redirects typically before rewrites.

A simple fix would be to move the first rule to the end.